# SVG in background-image

Tags: css, svg, sass

I am having this SASS:

```
.menu-inner .item-block .item-inner{
    border: none;
    background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%…20'><path%20d='M2,20l-2-2l8-8L0,2l2-2l10,10L2,20z'%20fill='%23fff'/></svg>);
}
```

But it is not working I keep getting error. `expected a variable name (e.g. $x) or ')' for the parameter list for url`

what am I missing?

Comment: Do you have those URL encoded characters (`%20`) and UTF8 characters (`…`) in your actual SASS? Or is that a copy + paste error?

Comment: It is encoded not any copy paste error.

Comment: Can you try like this

background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%…20'><path%20d='M2,20l-2-2l8-8L0,2l2-2l10,10L2,20z'%20fill='%23fff'/></svg>");

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SASS is trying to interpret your SVG as CSS/SASS. You should put quotes around the [`url`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/url) argument. Since there are single quotes in the SVG source, use double quotes around the argument.

```
.menu-inner .item-block .item-inner{
    border: none;
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg%20xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%…20'><path%20d='M2,20l-2-2l8-8L0,2l2-2l10,10L2,20z'%20fill='%23fff'/></svg>");
}
```

As an aside, the `…` character in your SVG seems out of place.